# How do I access a variable from another class to update my ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have this application that has a `ProgrressBar` on it.
I also have a class which acts as a `DownloadService` because it's being used in multiple ViewModels.

As you can see the function `DownloadData` simulates it downloading something and keeps track of the total amount of data that has been downloaded in percent, it goes from 0 - 100.

How do I make my `ProgressBar` get that same value as `totalDownloaded` without passing in the MainWindowViewModel as a parameter.

**MainWindow**

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <ProgressBar Height="25"
                     Maximum="100"
                     Value="{Binding ProgressValue}"/>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Width="100" Height="25"
                Content="Start"
                Command="{Binding StartDownloadCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private int _progressValue;

        public int ProgressValue
        {
            get { return _progressValue; }
            set
            {
                _progressValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        DownloadService ds = new DownloadService();

        public RelayCommand StartDownloadCommand { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            StartDownloadCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { ds.DownloadData(); }, o => true);
        }
    }
```

And the **DownloadService**

```
 class DownloadService
    {
        public void DownloadData()
        {
            int totalDownloaded = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
            {
                totalDownloaded++;
                Console.WriteLine(totalDownloaded);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reference **[`Progress<T> Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=netframework-4.8)**

> Provides an [`IProgress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=netframework-4.8) that invokes callbacks for each reported progress value.

Refactor the service to depend on `IProgress<int>` abstraction and use it to report progress

```
class DownloadService {
    public void DownloadData(IProgress<int> progress = null) {            
        int totalDownloaded = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
            totalDownloaded++;
            progress?.Report(totalDownloaded); // ?. just in case
            Console.WriteLine(totalDownloaded);
        }
    }
}
```

View model can pass a `Progress<int>` to the service to get reports of progress updates.

```
public MainWindowViewModel() {
    StartDownloadCommand = new RelayCommand(o => { 
        var progress = new Progress<int>(value => ProgressValue = value);
        ds.DownloadData(progress); 
    }, o => true);
}
```

explicitly depending on `IProgress<int>` avoids having to tightly couple the view model to the service.

Comment: That's amazing I had no idea that this was a thing, I knew there had to be something like it but wow.. Thank you! I love learning new cool things like that!